# What's the easiest way to convert a String such as "5:4" to a numerical value

Tags: android, kotlin

I a working with Strings with the format I've mentioned such as "5:4" and I need to get their value (for example "5:4" equals 1.25).

A simple `.toDouble()`, what would be the best approach

Comment: First find the index of `:` and then create two substring and then divide them

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
String a="5:4";
a= a.replaceAll(":", "/");
float result = new Expression(a).eval();
```

Comment: I couldn't use this expression in kotlin (didn't find the "Eval" function), but I've marked it as correct because the first suggestion you made in the comment for my question works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could `Iterable.reduce()` :

```
println(
        a.split(":").map { it.toDouble() }.reduce { a, b -> a / b }
) // 1.25
```

Answer (score 0):

A method with plain Kotlin using the `String.split()` method could look like this:

```
// INPUT
val ratio = "5:4" // can be "5/4" as well

// splits given string into a list and then cast it's members into Double
val items : List<Double> = (ratio.split(":", "/")).map { it.toDouble() } // [5, 4]

var result = 0.0
// calculate the ratio
if (items.size == 2 && items[1] != 0.0)
    result = items[0] / items[1]

println(result) // 1.25
```